# Не отображаются данные в диалоге jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, ajax

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Есть таблица с данными и кнопками: удалить, редактировать и сохранить. По щелчке на кнопку редактировать выполняется Ajax запрос; если запрос выполнился успешно, передаю в диалоговое окно результаты этого запроса. В итого данные в диалоговом окне почему-то не отображаются и после повторного щелчка на кнопку редактировать вылазит уже 3 окна и так нарастает с каждым разом.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pl_dialog = $('#pl_info');
    pl_dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    ("a[id ='ed_player']").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                pl_dialog.html(data);
                pl_dialog.dialog("open");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Какой тип данных вы получаете в ответе? И почему он не указан в опциях ajax? Думаю, что у вас опечатка, но всё-таки перемудрили вы с селектором:

```
("a[id ='ed_player']") // у вас
$('#ed_player') // исправленно
```

Хочется надеятся, что элементы с id "ed_player"  и "pl_info" у вас единичном экземпляре на странице. И Посмотрите, что вам приходит в ответе и приходит ли вообще (например, посмотреть в [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/))

Comment: Ну селектор я бы потом конечно поправил бы,это не столь важная проблема,в ответ приходит результат запроса ajax и еще 3 файла js

Comment: Спасибо разобрался с проблемой)) Оказывается на той страничке которую загружал в диалог были подключены файлы JS вот поэтому они в ответ и приходили.